# Implement multi svg icon react

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I was trying to implement complex icon component to build one icon with multiple svg.

I want to output like this

[image]

using these icons.

[image]

[image]

I have Icon components that accepts string of icon names and I tried passing icons as array but it seems not working as expected. Here's my code.

```
const arrIcons = [ 'ChevronRight', 'ChevronRight', 'ChevronRight', 'ArrowRight', ];
```

---

```
{arrIcons &&
 arrIcons.map((name, iconIndex) => (
  <Icon
  key={iconIndex}
  name={name as IconProps['name']}
  size={buttonIconSizes[size]}
 />
))}
```

And it outputs like this.
[image]